# "Failed of late" meaning?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

What is meant by "failed of late" in the following:

"How is your mother, Diana? Dear me, but she has
**failed of late**. She looks terrible run down."

?

Comment: Please use a dictionary. Dictionaries have been specifically created and optimized to look up the meaning of words and phrases. This site is not a dictionary, and is ill-suited to serve as one. By the time you were finished typing up your question here, a dictionary would have long given you the answer.

Comment: @RegDwight I searched Oxford and Cambridge and the closest thing I got was "Failing of Success". Posting here was my last resort. (PS: English is not my first language that's why it's kind of hard to me to understand such phrases as "Failing of late".)

Answer (score 1):

failed -- as in failing health

of late -- recently

So "Your mothers health has deteriorated recently"